# Python generating a dictionary from two lists

Tags: python, arrays, list, function, dictionary

I am trying to make a program that makes "tests". Starting with make_test(['jim', 'Jen'], 4) this should generate a dictionary where each of the student names (in this case two) is key and each student gets n (in this case 4) different "tests" as a list of lists (in other words: a list containing 4 lists, each with four integers). I showed the expected outcome at the end of the code below. The lists with tests is generated from the function make_eq, which again checks to see if the three criteriers in the function check is met. The code below seems to be working until the last function make_test. This probably has multiple errors. One of the errors are NameError: name 'res' is not defined - any ideas?

```
res = []
def check(ls):
    for n in ls:
        if n==0 or ls[0] == ls[2] or ls[1] == ls[3]:
            return False
    return True 

def make_eq(ls):   
    while len(res) < n:
        tmp = [randint(1,9),randint(1,9),randint(1,9),randint(1,9)]
        if check(tmp):
            res.append(tmp)
    return res

def make_test(students, n):  
    students = []
    tests = {}
    for student in students:
        for test in res:
            tests[student] = test
            res.remove(test)
    print(tests)

make_test(['jim', 'Jen'], 4)

#Expected Output:
#{'Jim': [[1, -3, -2, 1], [3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4], [-5, 6, -8, -1]],
#'Jen': [[3, 2, -9, 8], [1, -2, 9, 3], [5, -1, -2, 3], [9, -2, -3, -4]]}
```

Comment: You attempt to access a variable `res` inside `make_test()`, but no such variable is defined in that scope.

Comment: "res" is a local variable which isn't accessible from other functions. You can declare it as "global" (see Python docs).

Comment: Not directly the question, but your `check` function seems to be an inefficient way to ensure you don't have zeros or matching values in the data. Why don't you directly generate data that matches your criteria?

Comment: Please correct the following, then update your question.  Local variable 'res' is used in make_test but not defined.  Local variable 'n' in make_eq is not defined.

Comment: Thanks! Code updatet I tried to define res as global within make_test, but still the same error message. Not sure how to define the variable 'n' either. I am struggeling a bit to understand this.

Answer (score 1):

Res is defined locally under the function make_eq.
If you want the value of res, you have to return it from make_eq function with expected parameter and store in other res variable inside make_test.

Comment: Thats exactly right. I would like the value of res as input in make_test. I would like the loop in make_test to make a dictionary where student(name) is key and each student in the dictionary is assigned the content from res. Each new student should get another set of lists. In the example from the code above. The paramer 4 means that each student should get 4 lists, but Jim and Jen should get different content from res (does not matter if some of the variables is equal). I seem to be stuck